# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Alphabet = ["a","b","c","ç","d","e","f","g","ğ","h","ı","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","ö","p","r","s","ş","t","u","ü","v","y","z"]

message = 'cöimamiçknsyznhaczstş'
for i in range(len(message)):
    message = Alphabet.index(message[i])
```

I m trying to write simple code but I keep getting this `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`
error

I just want to get index of each char of message

Comment: in the first iteration of your loop you overwrite the string `message` with an integer (`Alphabet.index(...)`). in the second iteration you call `message[i]`. maybe rename on of those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly, just a little change is needed because in your code you are overwriting your `message` variable. Here is how you can fix it:

```
Alphabet = ["a","b","c","ç","d","e","f","g","ğ","h","ı","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","ö","p","r","s","ş","t","u","ü","v","y","z"]

message = 'cöimamiçknsyznhaczstş'
char_indexes = []

for i in range(len(message)): 
    char_indexes.append(Alphabet.index(message[i]))

print(char_indexes)
```

Another method to do the same is to use [List comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) as follows:

```
Alphabet = ["a","b","c","ç","d","e","f","g","ğ","h","ı","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","ö","p","r","s","ş","t","u","ü","v","y","z"]

message = 'cöimamiçknsyznhaczstş'

char_indexes = [Alphabet.index(message[i]) for i in range(len(message))]
print(char_indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first iteration, you assign to `message` the index of the first location of the first letter of the original `message` which is 2.
In the next iteration, `message=2` and you try to do `message[1]` but `message` is not an integer and therefore it is not subscriptable.

The solution is probably to change the loop to something like -

```
for i in range(len(message)):
    x = Alphabet.index(message[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `message` and it becomes integer after first iteration.
Try this:

```py
Alphabet = ["a","b","c","ç","d","e","f","g","ğ","h","ı","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","ö","p","r","s","ş","t","u","ü","v","y","z"]

placeholder_list = []
message = "cöimamiçknsyznhaczstş"
for i in range(len(message)):
    placeholder_list.append(Alphabet.index(message[i]))
print(placeholder_list)
```